# Accessing `proc` file-system to read `/proc/[pid]/some-file` from a system app

Tags: security, permissions, file-permissions, android-source, selinux

I have a custom A10 repo in which I'm trying to create an app that would be able to read `/proc/[pid]/some-file` files e.g. `stat` and `status`, kind of like `ps` does.

Having read this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207115/) it was clear that a `AID_READPROC` should be added which I have done using a custom permission.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.poke.mon"
    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system">
<!-- More stuff -->
         <uses-permission android:name="com.poke.READPROC_PERM" />
<!-- More stuff -->
  </application>
</manifest>
```

I have added `com.poke.READPROC_PERM` by editing the appropriate `platform.xml`, `AndroidManifest.xml` and `sytem-current.txt` files and allowing that permission in the `privapp-permissions` file

I have validated by `cat`-ing the `status` file for my app's process and verifying that gid 3009 is indeed present.

However I was still being blocked by sepolicy (with the enforcement disabled the code could access the files).

Adding `r_dir_file(priv_app, proc)` to the `priv_app.te` resulted in errors.

The reason given by the compiler was this [line](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-10.0.0_r30:system/sepolicy/private/coredomain.te;l=91) in `coredomain.te` :

```
# Core domains are not permitted to use kernel interfaces which are not
# explicitly labeled.
# TODO(b/65643247): Apply these neverallow rules to all coredomain.
full_treble_only(`
  # /proc
  neverallow {
    coredomain
    -init
    -vold
  } proc:file no_rw_file_perms;
```

Creating a custom domain resulted in similar errors as I probably want to

```
typeattribute my_apps_domain coredomain;
```

To avoid a lot of complexity and duplication (I need to communicate with other services etc.).

Is there a way to work around that limitation? (e.g. looking at `genfscon` it doesn't seem to support wildchar mapping e.g. `/proc/\d+/some-file`)

It also seems weird that `shell` is able to do `ps` just fine yet it's also `coredomain` defined by the [first line](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-10.0.0_r30:system/sepolicy/private/shell.te;l=1) of `shell.te`:

```
typeattribute shell coredomain;
```

So maybe there's some other magical sepolicy door I'm missing?

Comment: App development is off-topic here. I am voting to migrate this question to Stackoverflow.com.

Comment: From an end user's perspective, you can turn `avc` denials from `dmesg` into SEPolicy rules and inject them during runtime using Magisk's `supoliy` tool. My existing answers may help: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A218526+supolicy

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks, your answers were helpful, however I am trying to allow that at build time so that, there won't be any involvement from the user after. I used `audit2allow` to generate the new rules but as I mentioned the build says they contradict some neverallow rule

Answer (score 0):

1. Define an custom domain for your app：

   user=_app isPrivApp=true seinfo=platform name=com.myapp.packagename domain=my_custom_domain type=app_data_file levelFrom=all

ref:https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:device/google/coral-sepolicy/private/seapp_contexts;drc=01b96a3a966f075abcba27cb415cece348a3278e;l=5

2. Label the custom domain as coredomain:

   typeattribute my_custom_domain coredomain;

Then you will work with the neverallow limit.