# How to get the complete output of all running processes from 'top' command on Android Q?

Tags: android, command, android-source

I am running top command from a system application on Android Q through
`ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("top", "-b", "-n", "1")` and parsing the output to fetch the CPU, Memory usage of desired process. But the output of 'top' command is restricted in this case and is showing only the processes running with **USER** as system. I want to fetch the CPU and Memory usage of other process running with their own user id. For e.g. u2_a99 or root. These processes are not listed in the top command output. I also tried running through a separate shell:

```
    String[] cmd = {"sh","-c", "top -b -n 1"};
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
```

or fetching information through ps command by running `ps -A -o name,%cpu,%mem` from ProcessBuilder. But the output is restricted in this case also and shows only a few processes. How can I get the complete output of all the running processes from top/ps command?

Comment: This a restriction of the system itself. It can only be bypassed using root permissions.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66348160/accessing-proc-file-system-to-read-proc-pid-some-file-from-a-system-app/66468077